# How to launch Wolfram Workbench?

Tags: workbench

I begin to use Wolfram Workbench, so need some assistance. I properly installed Workbench and Eclipse. Eclipse shows Workbench's icon in the About Eclipse IDE window.

But I have no idea about how to launch Workbench.

Section **Starting the Workbench** in Workbench documentation begins with the words:

*When the Workbench is launched, the first thing you see is a dialog .....*

But how to launch? No mention.

Comment: If you use the Workbench plugin for Eclipse then there is nothing to launch; just use the functionality within Eclipse.

Comment: Thanks. Just created my first project!

Comment: I think the actual Wolfram Workbench documentation is largely outdated, to the point where oftentimes it is more confusing than useful.